# MySql Database import is not working with java web application

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications, import

I want to import mysql database using java on web application but unfortunately the mysql.exe process get stuck and next Line of code does not get executed which make browser to keep on loading.

**restore.xhtml**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <p:commandButton value="1 click restore"       
    action="#restoreBean.oneClickRestore()}" update="all,g" ajax="false"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**RestoreBean.java**

```
String absPath ="C:/Users/sms/build/web/resources/backup/backuproot.sql";
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql ", dbName, "-u " + dbUser, "-p " + dbPwd, "-e ", " \"source "+ absPath+" \""};

try{
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();// after this line no line of code get executed; in taskmanager u can see mysql.exe
    if (processComplete == 0) {
        restoreMsg = "Successfully restored from SQL : " + absPath;
    } else {
        restoreMsg = "Error at restoring";
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
      Logger.getLogger(RestoreBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But the same code runs well and database get imported when used in console application

**RestoreDbTest.java**

```
public class RestoreDbTest{
     public static void main(String[] args)  {
        RestoreDbTest b = new RestoreDbTest();
          b.restoreDatabase("root", "", "b.sql");
    }


 public boolean restoreDatabase(String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String source) {
       String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql ", dbName, "-u " + dbUser, "-p " + dbPwd, "-e ", " \"source b.sql \""};

        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
              //  log.info("Backup restored successfully with " + source);
                return true;
            } else {
                //log.info("Could not restore the backup " + source);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getCause());
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

**mysql process list**

[image]

Comment: Did you test the generated mysql command from the command line of your system to see if it then executes? Plus look into the mysql for the running command (no idea how long it should run but with `show processlist` you might be able to see something)

Comment: in command line it works fine and even in java console application same code works fine but in web i dont know why things are not going well